# How to Motorize the LEGO Mars Rover

Tags: technic, motor, power-functions, gears, remote-control

I am looking for some suggestions.

My daughter is building the Mars Rover set (go here for the details: http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=98222) for a presentation at school and I told her I would help make it operate by remote control with one of the power function kits. Problem is that it is a lot more complex than I thought. (I have no experience at the expert LEGO building).

I think I can maybe get it moving with a remote, receiver, and simple motor attached to one wheel, but I do not have any idea how to do the steering and don’t know how to move any of the other functions (camera, antenna, robotic arm).  see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrGmxwcLcUE

So, to steer, I use a servo?

How do I operate the other things, more servos?

And to move things slowly, do I need complex gearing?

Any suggestions to help me figure out what I need to do and what to buy to easily make this work would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The biggest issue will be that it doesn't appear designed to be driven. The best shot are the middle wheels, but a cursory glance doesn't provide any obvious answers. Is it on a rocker like the actual rover? That eliminates another possible recourse.

Comment: @jncraton Thanks so much for the response.  I don’t think it is on a rocker.  Here is a photo of the underside.  http://www.brickpicker.com/images/set_images/medium/brickpicker_set_7471_2.jpg

Answer (score 2):

With some minor adjustments, you can try adding [Lego Power Functions](http://powerfunctions.lego.com/en-us/default.aspx) to your Technic parts.

With the appropriate parts, you can motorize your wheels with motors then remote control them with the Infrared Sensor with remote control. It would be rather tight though as sets that ***can*** allow space for these functions will show the option for Power Functions on the box. This means that the Lego Mars Rover set might not be compatible with this set unless you can add some major adjustments or make a rover yourself!

You can find pieces and their details here: http://powerfunctions.lego.com/en-us/whatis/default.aspx#HowDoesPFWorkContentProvider